# Dynamic matrix and dynamic values into matrix

Tags: c

This is my code - i init my own values (1 or 0) into a defined matrix.
instead of setting always a hardcoded matrix i want the user to set values and the dimantions of the matrix
 scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);
and after building the matrix to initscan his value
scanf("%d", &vall);

Please help me with this i never done something dynamic this way and dont know how to load dynamix matrix with dynamic values straight from the user please show me your syntax for this so i could learn.

```
printf("How many Row : ");
scanf("%d", &nrow);

rowptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * nrow);

printf("How many Column : ");
scanf("%d", &ncol);
```

thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WIDTH 50
#define HEIGHT 20

void init(int board[][WIDTH], int rows) {
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            board[y][x] = 0;
    /* Scatter some live cells: */
    board[10][25] = 1;
    board[10][26] = 1;
    board[10][27] = 1;
    board[11][25] = 1;
    board[12][26] = 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific question here?

Comment: I asked to show how to make the matrix dyanmix cause i know only build thos matrix with defining their sizes at the begining

Answer (score 2):

You can use `malloc()` function for this. `malloc()` takes the number of bytes as parameter and returns a `void` pointer on success. You'll need to cast it to the pointer of the appropriate data type to use it. Here's an example:

```
int **board;
scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);

// first allocate memory for pointer to each row
board = (int**) malloc(height * sizeof(int*));

// then allocate memory for each row
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    board[i] = (int*) malloc(width * sizeof(int));
```

And when you're done, free up the allocated memory to avoid memory leak. You have to free them in reverse order:

```
// first free up each row
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    free(board[i]);

// then free up the pointers to the rows
free(board);
```

**Edit:**

For your code, do this:

```
printf("How many Row : ");
scanf("%d", &nrow);

rowptr = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int) * nrow);

printf("How many Column : ");
scanf("%d", &ncol);

for(i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
    rowptr[i] = (int*) malloc(ncol * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: i cannot fugure out how to use this- can you please show me the implamantation using my code?

Comment: but your solution is for array? i need 2d matrix...can you please show how that done?

Comment: What's the difference between a 2D array and a matrix? Go through the code carefully and read the comments of the first code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) function to assign memory dinamically. It returns a pointer to a block of memory of the requested size. Here's an example:

```
int size;
int *foo;

printf("How many elements? ");
scanf("%d", &size);

foo = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

// always check if the call succeeded
if(foo == NULL) {
    printf("can't allocate memory!");
    return;
}

int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("enter value for element #%d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &foo[i]);
}

// ...

free(foo);    // to avoid memory leaks
```

[free()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/) tells the os that the block you pass in is no longer in use, so it's available for the future.

Now, since you want a matrix, you need a double pointer and you have to call malloc for every "row" (error checking removed for clarity):

```
int **matrix = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));

int i;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: is it possiable to do this only inside the init function?

Comment: your code is good for array but i need 2d matrix - can you show how that would look?

Answer (score 0):

To have a solution with a full dynamic arrays of arrays (a 2D matrix with number of rows and columns unknown at compile time), you should use an `int **` type to represent your matrix.

```
int **board = malloc(height * sizeof *board);
for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    board[i] = malloc(width * sizeof **board);
```

then prototype your functions with an `int **` for the board parameter and access your matrix as usual:

```
int x = board[i][j];   // store in x the element of row i and column j
```

Comment: can you please explain more - i wrote a code for scanf the matrix dymantions and added to the question - after reciving the values how can i replace my defined values?

Comment: @Blondy21 you originally used `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` constants for you rows and columns, so I used `height` and `width` to express that they are no longer C constants. In your new question edit, consider my `height` to be your `nrow` and my `width` to be your `ncol`.

Comment: @Blondy21 my first lines of program show how to dynamically allocate the  `board` matrix. The last line show you can still simply access elements of the matrix with the `board[i][j]` notation.

Comment: no, the generalization for modern C for dynamically allocated matrices are VLA, not simulating 2D arrays via pointers of pointers.

Comment: @JensGustedt I disagree. VLA are optional in the current standard (C11) and my opinion is to avoid VLA at all costs. Moreover allocating large arrays of arrays in the stack (VLA can only be automatic objects) can be dangerous and easily lead to stack overflows.

Comment: @ouah, VLA don't need to be allocated on the stack, this is an urban myth. Please see my answer. Pointers to pointers are really bad, because they need a lot of care to allocate, initialize and free properly. They scare off beginners making them believe that C, wow, this is really a complicated language. No it isn't. Just do what the standard offers as concepts. You also could have a look into http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/dont-be-afraid-of-variably-modified-types/

Answer (score 0):

If you have modern C, say C99, initializing a matrix dimension with variable content is possible. It is called *variable length array*, VLA. On what concerns your code, you are almost there. Just change your prototypes to something like the following

```
void init(size_t cols, size_t rows, int board[rows][cols])
```

such that the bounds come first and are known when you come to the declaration of the matrix.

You could principally allocate such matrices on the stack

```
int board[rows][cols];
```

(without initializer) would do, but if your dimension get large you'd risk stack overflow. To declare a matrix on the heap, you could do something like

```
int (*board)[cols] = malloc(int[rows][cols]);
```

don't forget to assign initial values to the individual entries `board[i][j]` and to free the whole matrix at the end of its use.

*Edit:* seeing all these answers that try to sell you simulations of 2D arrays via pointers to pointers. Don't do such complicated things, just do what the language provides you directly, VLA.